# Having to switch between secure and unsecure boot all the time

Tags: windows, boot, bios, uefi, manjaro

I've recently dual booted Manjaro and Windows 11, and have run into a conflict that seems impossible to solve.

I've read that one can **not** boot Manjaro on secure boot. At the same time, an online game(Valorant) that I play weekly, if not daily, **requires** Windows to be in secure boot.

Does anyone have any idea about how I can solve this, so that I don't have to enter my bios menu to enable/disable secure boot on a daily basis?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

> Having to switch between secure and un-secure boot all the time .... Having to switch between secure and unsecure boot all the time

Yes.  Do not use dual boot for this task.

Use a Virtual Machine instead.

Now given you are running Windows 11 which requires secure boot and other security measures, make Windows 11 your host machine and make Manjaro your guest.

My preference for a VM App is VMware Workstation Pro. I have that on Windows 11 Pro and Kali and Ubuntu guests that perform fast and well.

Hyper-V also works, and Windows 11 here needs to be the Pro version.  I have an Insider machine with Hyper-V running; however, I prefer the flexibility of VMware Workstation.

However you proceed, a Virtual Machine will solve your issue and let you also experiment with other types of guest machines.

Comment: There is one possible solution, that should work for an unspecified amount of time, simply run Windows 10 since the security checks that Valorant uses is only applicable to Windows 11. However, I agree using a VM or WSL2, is a better solution to the author's problem.  Manjaro is not officially support by WSL2, so something else would have to be used, but everything is a compromise.

Comment: If you are willing to go the unofficial route to get Manjaro support you could use [this](https://github.com/sirredbeard/Awesome-WSL/pull/77) to achieve that goal.